# Using Access VBA store the primary key of an object clicked in a variable

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I'm trying to create a shopping basket of sorts. I have displayed on a subform gif images of products(doors) all of which belong to the same field. When one of the images is selected id like to assign the ID of the selected attachment to a variable which I can use on the subforms master. Can anyone point me in the right direction??

```
Private Sub Door_View_Click()

Dim strSelected As String
Dim IDnumber As String

strSelcted = Door_View.FileName
IDnumber = DoCmd.RunSQL("SELECT Door_ID Where Door_View = strSelected")



End Sub
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Doubt thatll be much help but that's the best ive got so far. I'm not sure how to assign the filename of the attachment that has been clicked to the strSelected.

Comment: If the form is bound to the table/query, you can get it by `IDnumber = Me![Door_ID]`. Otherwise change `DoCmd.RunSQL` with `DLookup`. See the access help for the DLookup function.